# How to do text to speech with python on a Toshiba laptop and Windows 7?

Tags: python, mp3, text-to-speech, wav, pyinstaller

I am trying to find a way to create text to speech in python (I am on windows 7). I am using pyinstaller to compile this program. I have tried a large number of approaches, including using Google's unofficial text to speech program accessed through the urllib2 module. This ends up creating an mp3 file. For details on the code, much of this code is from http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/11/text-to-speech-with-correct-intonation.html. I have then needed to play the mp3 file that this generates. I have used mplayer, ffmpeg, mp3play, audiere, pydub, and pygame all with the same results: no sound was played, yet no exceptions were raised. I have even used the same pygame code on a raspberry pi and successfully played an mp3 file. I have also tried converting it to a wav file, which has worked fine, only when I try to play it with pygame or winsound, the same thing happens. No sound, no exceptions. My current code uses winsound, playing a wav file that I can successfully play in the windows media player (I can even open it in windows media player from python, using os.startfile()). Here it is:

```
winsound.PlaySound("file.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)    #the wav file is in the same directory as the program
```

I am also trying to use pygame mixer an music modules. For example:

```
init()                            #this is pygame.init(), I only imported init and the mixer module
pygame.mixer.init()               #initializes pygame.mixer
pygame.mixer.music.load(filename) #loads it in music
pygame.mixer.music.play()         #plays it in music
time.sleep(20)
```

I have even played sounds from python successfully with the winsound and win32api Beep() functions. However, this obviously cannot play an mp3 or wav file. I have also tried a completely different text to speech engine, which plays the sound without an mp3 file in the mix, using pyttsx:

```
import pyttsx

engine = pyttsx.init()

def tts(mytext):
    engine.say(mytext)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

This  has also failed to create sound, or raise an exception. Because of this pattern, I have a feeling that this has something to do with the system, but it doesn't seem like it is something obvious.

Because this almost definitely has something to do with the hardware (pygame.mixer has worked this way on different hardware, and I am sure it usually works on windows) it may be important to know I am using a Toshiba laptop. Also, I am using python 2.7.

Ideally, I would like to do this with pygame, because I have the most experience using it and there are some sound editing features I would like to access in pygame if at all possible.

I also tried using 64 bit python (I was using 32 bit python on 64 bit windows 7). It still failed to work.

I also tried playing an mp3 file inside a Ubuntu virtual box environment, but on the same device. It still didn't work. This isn't particularly surprising because virtualbox uses a lot of the resources (like screen and wifi) from the host operating system, hence it wouldn't necessarily play sounds any differently. Any way around this would be helpful. Some sounds play fine, just not specifically mp3 or wav files in python, so there is probably a solution.

Comment: what does the url of the mp3 file in your code look like?

Comment: Url? It is an mp3 file in my filesystem, I do not believe it has a url. It is just called file.mp3

Comment: add a `print mp3`, let me see what it is. Local files have urls too, something like `C:\Users\....\file.mp3`.

Comment: The file is in the same directory as the program, so a file path shouldn't be necessary. Here is the file path of the program and the mp3 file: C:\Users\Student\Documents\notes\file.mp3 and C:\Users\Student\Documents\notes\program.py

Comment: Why are you sure that the path is not necessary?

Comment: Typically programs will look in the current working directory if a path is not supplied with the filename. I see your point, though, I will try including the full file path.

Comment: It still raises the same exception. By the way an alternative solution could be to use the pygame2exe code supplied online to use pygame, which will probably work quite well.

Comment: The error does not seem to be happening due to a missing MP3 file, but rather due to a missing/faulty MPlayer installation.

Comment: That is entirely possible. I'll look into it.

Comment: Because I am trying to make a text to speech program, I have also tried using pyttsx. It also made no sound (without exceptions).

Comment: The say() function of the speech module has also not worked

Comment: I know this is probably not what you're looking for, but have you looked into what it would take to make your own mp3 player?  If you're clever you could probably do it pretty simply with a combination of ```subprocess``` and ```threading```.  But of course, I haven't looking into this with any great depth, so I may be wrong

Comment: Interesting idea. This might work, but I have used a lot of mp3 players and not created sound, so I suspect this might have something to do with my system, and not the programs. Furthermore, I have used pygame.mixer successfully on a different computer. Because I have made sound on this computer with the winsound and win32api Beep functions, I suppose this would work if I reduced an mp3 file to a set of tones with pitch and duration. I believe there is a simpler solution to this, but I will try that if there is not.

Comment: If you're accessing the generated file *immediately* after you synthesize it, the file may still be opened by the synthesizer. If your synthesizer call is synchronous, try putting an artificial wait after the synthesizer finishes for the file to be released. If it's asynchronous, you'll have to monitor the file somehow yourself. We had a similar problem using the C#/.NET windows speech engine where the file was locked up and not immediately available.

Comment: I have experimented with adding wait commands in my code. I also have actually failed to play a different mp3 file that was on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens I recently had an idea that led me to take another shot at this. This solution is extremely hackish and shouldn't be necessary but unfortunately it is. Basically what I do is open the file in windows media player but suppress the window using subprocess. I already have the basic answer at this question, so [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678955/automating-windows-media-player/26499095#26499095) because I don't much care to rewrite the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This error says that it can't find a executable of MPlayer since you just use a mplayer wrapper.

```
File ".\program.py", line 1681, in playsound
        player = mplayer.Player()
      File "C:\Users\Student\Documents\notes\mplayer.py", line 109, in __init__
        self.spawn()
      File "C:\Users\Student\Documents\notes\mplayer.py", line 319, in spawn
        close_fds=(not subprocess.mswindows))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

You can get a MPlayer binary from here: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html

Most other python programs use ffmpeg and writing some wrapper scripts to play mp3 files.

Maybe you can get inspired by [music-player](https://github.com/albertz/music-player)

Also there is a page at the official Python site where you could find some libraries. https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic
But be ware, most of them are outdated.

The problem with pygame is, that you need to check if the music is playing and hold your program open as long as music is playing.

This could be done like this:

```
FRAMERATE = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mixer.music.load(soundfile)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    clock.tick(FRAMERATE)
```

Edit: and to your bounty, there is not a really simple solution if you won't use pygame and the included sdl library.
it's better to swap out py2exe / create your own "exe" without py2exe.

Comment: In the pygame approach, I am actually already just implementing a lengthy time.sleep(), which has worked for me before. I have actually played sound successfully with pygame on a raspberry pi.

Comment: that sounds somhow creepy... is your sound card working?? (i know that questions suck) but sometimes... you don't see the plank in front of the head

Comment: I can play sounds using the windows media player properly, just not in python. Actually, I can even create sound in python with the win32api and winsound Beep() functions, which just generate a beep at one pitch for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `mp3play` module for python. If it works for you, and works with `py2exe`, then it's a very easy module to use. The docs page I like to says it needs win xp to run, but I use it successfully on win7

For example:

```
import mp3play

filename = r'C:\Documents and Settings\Michael\Desktop\music.mp3'
mp3 = mp3play.load(filename)

mp3.play()

# Let it play for up to 30 seconds, then stop it.
import time
time.sleep(min(30, mp3.seconds()))
mp3.stop()
```

Check it out [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mp3play/)

Comment: I have downloaded mp3play, and while this looks like it should work. Again, no sound is played, without exceptions. I have a feeling this might have something to do with the mp3 file still being written to, but I am not sure because the mp3 file plays fine in the windows media player.

Comment: when you say the mp3 file is still being written to while you are trying to play it, what do you mean exactly? Also, is it the same story with any mp3 file?

Comment: Just before I play the mp3 file, I create it (I am using Google's unofficial text to speech program). I will try using a different mp3 file.

Comment: how are you creating the mp3? Is is possible that there is something going wrong with the encoding?

Comment: I am using urllib2 to access Google's text to speech program, at http://translate.google.com/translate_tts. Then I open a file, and send the urllib2 opener's read() function to the write() function of the file, then close the file. Basically, I get the data from urrlib2, write it to the file, and close the file.

Comment: A different mp3 file had the same result of not playing. I have, however, succeeded in opening both the mp3 file that I create and the one that I do not in the windows media player, just by using os.startfile()