# How to change the running speed of video while running with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to run video using python script with VLC media player. I found the subprocess function to open and run my video repeatedly, the problem is that I can't find a way to change the speed of my video while running.

```
import subprocess
speed = {1: "--rate=1.0", 2: "--rate=1.5", 3: "--rate=2.0", 4: "--rate=2.5", 5: "--rate=3.0"}   # speed options
speed_selection =1 #the speed for first play
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\Vlc.exe",      # open and play vlc media player
                  r'''C:\Users\user\Desktop\Arduino_project\Riding_Bicycle.mp4''',
                  "--repeat","--fullscreen","--no-video-title",speed[speed_selection]])
```

Comment: Not sure if that works, but you can look at `win32com` and control VLC using ActiveX or something like what... I only found an example with Windows Media Player (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678955/automating-windows-media-player/26499095)

Comment: https://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX/ or https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

Comment: There also seems to be some Python interface: https://wiki.videolan.org/PythonBinding/